# How do we deduce this fisher information relation?

Tags: self-study, variance, information-theory, fisher-information

Given a RS $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}$ whose distribution is well known (unless its parameters), how do we prove the following Fischer Information relationship
\begin{align*}
I_{F}(\theta) =\textbf{E}\left[\left(\frac{\partial\ln f(\textbf{X}|\theta)}{\partial\theta}\right)^{2}\right] = -\textbf{E}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}\ln f(\textbf{X}|\theta)}{\partial\theta^{2}}\right]
\end{align*}

**MY APPROACH**

To begin with, I started with the observation that
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial^{2}\ln f(\textbf{X}|\theta)}{\partial\theta^{2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left[\frac{\partial\ln f(\textbf{X}|\theta)}{\partial\theta}\right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left[\frac{1}{f(\textbf{X}|\theta)}\frac{\displaystyle\partial f(\textbf{X}|\theta)}{\displaystyle\partial \theta}\right] = \ldots
\end{align*}

But I do not know how to proceed from here. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your way, calling $f(\textbf{X}|\theta)=f$, for notational simplicity:
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial\theta^2}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\frac{\partial\ln f}{\partial\theta}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right)\\&=-\frac{1}{f^2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right)^2+\frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\theta^2}\end{align}$$

Note that the first summand, call it $\mathcal{F}$, can be manipulated as:
$$\mathcal{F}=-\left(\frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right)^2=-\left(\frac{\partial\ln f}{\partial\theta}\right)^2$$
because inner term is the same with the rightmost term we found in the first line.

For the second summand, we have:
$$E\left[\frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\theta^2}\right]=\int_X \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\theta^2}dx=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\left(\int_X fdx\right)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}(1)=0$$
So, only the first summand remains non-zero, which is what we need to find. Note that. in order for this equation to be true, the differentiation by $\theta$ needs to be drawn out of the integral via assumed [*regularity*](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/%7Esuhasini/teaching613/inference.pdf) conditions.

Comment: The notation is brief to the point of being (potentially) confusing.  Does "$dX$" mean "$f(x)dx$"?  How do you obtain the last two inequalities (neither of which seem correct)?

Comment: $dX$ is as is because $$E\left[\frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\theta^2}\right]=\int \frac{1}{f(X|\theta)}\frac{\partial^2 f(X|\theta)}{\partial\theta^2}f(X|\theta)dX=\int \frac{\partial^2 f(X|\theta)}{\partial\theta^2}dX$$. Which one is the other confusing one? The equality for $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: It appears you have evaluated "$\int f dX$" as "$f(1)$" rather than as $1.$  The use of a capital $X$ to denote both a random variable and variable of integration technically works but is potentially confusing.

Comment: Hi@gunes, How can I link this:"first summand non-zero" and "second zero" to fisher information? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Yiffany, when the second summand is zero, the first summand in the expectation formula becomes what the OP was asking, i.e. the first equation in the OP, LHS.

Comment: I see, is it correct? $-\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial\theta^2} \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[\frac{1}{f^2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \right)^2 \right]  =\mathbb{E} \left[\left(\frac{\partial\ln f}{\partial\theta}\right)^2 \right]$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.