# Prove second derivative of loglikelihood is Fisher information

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, self-study, bayesian

### Problem

Prove below equation , fisher information come from negative of second derivative of likelihood.

$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}(\theta) = \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(y;\theta)}\left[-\nabla^2_{\theta'} \log p(y;\theta')|_{\theta'=\theta}\right]
\end{align*}$$

### My current thought

$$
\nabla_{\theta'} \log p(y;\theta') = \frac{1}{p(y;\theta')}\nabla_{\theta'} p(y;\theta')
$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\nabla^2_{\theta'} \log p(y;\theta')
    & = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'}\Big(\frac{1}{p(y;\theta')}\nabla_{\theta'} p(y;\theta')\Big) \\
 & = \frac{1}{p(y;\theta')^2}\nabla_{\theta'} p(y;\theta')\nabla_{\theta'} p(y;\theta')
\end{align*}$$

Then, I have no idea what next ...

Comment: This is answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404530/how-do-we-deduce-this-fisher-information-relation